# How do I stop firefox from reloading on start?

Tags: firefox

I want firefox to only load a blank page when I start it, nothing else at all. That's why my homepage is about:blank. However it loads all the tabs I had up last time, and I can't work out how to make it not do this. Any ideas?
[image: The correct option is enabled. It still reloads all the tabs.]

Comment: [You should just disable the feaure](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/975670)

Comment: Yeah, tried it, as you can see in my edit there. Sometimes it works, sometimes it loads up old tabs. I can't find any consistent reason.